# Convert SAS7BCAT into DATASET

Tags: sas, catalog

I try to open a SAS CATALOG file (SAS7BCAT) with SAS ENTERPRISE GUIDE. And I receive always this message :

> ```
>  ERROR: File DIFTFMT.FORMATSX64.CATALOG was created for a different
>  operating system.
> ```

Who could convert my CATALOG format in a  DATASET format? Like this I will be able to create my own catalog!

Thank you in advance.

For your information : The operating system used to create this CATALOG file is 9.0401B0X64_S08R2

The code which retunrs the error :

```
/* SAS CODE BEGIN*/

libname diftfmt '/ec/local/sas/data/training/OrionStar/orfmt';

options fmtsearch=(diftfmt);

PROC FORMAT library=diftfmt.formatsx64 fmtlib;

RUN;

/* SAS CODE END*/
```

The code to find the operating system:

```
/* SAS CODE BEGIN*/

filename test 
"/ec/local/sas/data/training/OrionStar/orfmt/formatsx64.sas7bcat";

DATA enc (keep=encoding); 

 length encoding $ 20;

 infile test truncover scanover; 

 input @'9.0' enc $14.; 

 encoding = '9.0' || enc; 

RUN;

/* SAS CODE END*/
```

Comment: You can ask SAS support to help.  Are you using a commercial version of SAS? If so you are already paying for support so it can't hurt to ask SAS if they can help.  If you have a large volume of catalogs that need converting they will probably, rightly, charge for the service.

Comment: You need cport on source and cimport on destination to convert everything in catalog

Comment: Thank you Tom...
Yes, I received this version from my team. They previously followed the cursus.
I understand nom the difficulty to have the same operating system so I will ask to the SAS accounter a DATASET version of the CATALOG.

Comment: Thank you Lee... The thing is that I tried the CPORT on my environment and it didn't work...I understood that I have to use this on CPORT an equivalent system (system used to create the CATALOG)...So....I will wait the DATASET...